Where did the Annunciation occur?
Where did the Annunciation occur? In Sts. Joachim & Anna's home or in St. Joseph's home?

I found this in the low quality queue for lacking length or content. Speaking to the choir, it's more than sufficient, but Stack Exchange expects us to address a larger audience than that and so it would have been appropriate to cite and summarize the story of the Annunciation, why you feel the question isn't readily answered from scripture or Church writings, and perhaps why the question is important. I'm not sure this warrants closure, though.

Where did the Annunciation occur?
Where did the Annunciation occur? In Sts. Joachim and Anna's home or in St. Joseph's home?
This question is impossible to answer. The historical evidence is not available to us at our present moment in time.

What we do know about Mary comes to us from the Gospel evangelists Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John. In the early centuries of the Church, many traditions arose around Mary and her life. Some have no foundation in Scripture, such as her presentation in the temple (observed on Nov. 21). And even with the events recorded in sacred Scripture, many questions remain unanswered. This is true for the Annunciation, celebrated liturgically on March 25.
St. Luke only mentions that the Annunciation took place in Nazareth; he does not tell us where in Nazareth. The origination of the event taking place at a spring is found in the Protoevangelium of James, an apocryphal text, which indicates that Mary heard the angel’s greeting at the well but did not see the angel until she returned home.
Maximus the Confessor aligns himself with the East, citing the Protoevangelium of James in his text. His description is as follows: “And when, how, and where did the Annunciation take place? The virgin was fasting and standing in prayer near a fountain, because she conceived the fountain of life.” Unlike the Protoevangelium of James, Maximus does not place Mary as leaving and then receiving a further revelation in her home.
The Western mystical texts give little consideration to the location of the Annunciation. Ven. Mary of Agreda writes:
The whole of this celestial army with their princely leader holy Gabriel directed their flight to Nazareth, a town of the province of Galilee, to the dwelling place of most Holy Mary. This was a humble cottage and her chamber was a narrow room.
Similarly, Bl. Anne Catherine Emmerich places the Annunciation in Mary’s room. An interesting nuance between the three vitae is the day on which the Annunciation occurred. Maximus states that it was a Sunday, whereas Ven. Maria of Agreda claims it was a Thursday at 6 o’clock.
Both accounts provide a rich symbolism. The event occurring at a well allows us to reflect on Jesus as the life-giving water and also find a connection to other encounters at wells in the Gospels. Some have placed the acclamation of Elizabeth to Mary at a water well, and we think of Jacob’s Well and the Woman at the Well (see John 4).
There also is a richness to the West’s private Annunciation, in which we are invited into the prayerful and intimate exchange between Mary and the angel. While there is theological significance to either of the theories, the exact location in a bigger perspective is a quite minute and unnecessary detail. Yet knowing the different locations allows us to envision the event when we close our eyes in meditative prayer. - What Do We Know About The Annunciation?

To complicate the process of discovery as to where the Annunciation actually occurred, we have to contemplate the the fact that both the Orthodox Church and Catholicism hold that Mary lived in the temple in Jerusalem until the time of the Annunciation and that when Mary’s time of service at the temple in Jerusalem, her parents may not have been alive. Tradition holds that both Joachim and Anne were elderly when Mary was presented to the temple.

The Presentation of the Blessed Virgin Mary, known in the East as The Entry of the Most Holy Theotokos into the Temple, is a liturgical feast celebrated on November 21 by the Catholic, Eastern Orthodox, and some Anglo-Catholic Churches.
The feast is associated with an event recounted not in the New Testament, but in the apocryphal Protoevangelium of James. According to that text, Mary's parents, Joachim and Anne, who had been childless, received a heavenly message that they would have a child. In thanksgiving for the gift of their daughter, they brought her, when still a child, to the Temple in Jerusalem to consecrate her to God. Later versions of the story (such as the Gospel of Pseudo-Matthew and the Gospel of the Nativity of Mary) indicate that Mary was taken to the Temple at around the age of three in fulfillment of a vow. Tradition held that she was to remain there to be educated in preparation for her role as Mother of God.
In the Eastern Orthodox tradition, this is one of the days when women named Mary (Μαρία in Greek) and Despoina (Δέσποινα) celebrate their name day.
The account of the Presentation of the Blessed Virgin Mary in the Temple is principally based on the Protoevangelium of James, which has been dated by historians prior to the year 200 AD. The story relates that in thanksgiving for the birth of their daughter Mary, Joachim and Anne decide to consecrate her to God, and bring her, at the age of three years, to the temple in Jerusalem. Mary's presentation in the temple draws parallels to that of the prophet Samuel, whose mother Hannah, like Anne, was also thought to be barren, and who offered her child as a gift to God at Shiloh.
Mary remained in the Temple until her twelfth year, at which point Joseph was assigned to be her guardian. According to Coptic tradition, her father Joachim died when Mary was six years old and her mother when Mary was eight.
"This story is a legend with no foundation in history and the point of the story is to show that even in her childhood Mary was completely dedicated to God. However, it is from this very account that arose the feast of Mary's Presentation." - Presentation of Mary

So was the Annunciation at St. Joachim and Anne’s home, St. Joseph’s domain or at some other relative’s of the Virgin Mary’s place, we may never be sure with any amount of certitude.
What we do know is that it was a common custom for the bride to join the groom’s father’s household, rather than the groom and the bride establishing their own household. So, if the bride and groom were of a marriageable age, the groom would return to his father’s house after the betrothal to prepare a bridal chamber. Whether or not this actually happened is impossible to determine!

It occurred in her father St. Joachim's house:
Matt 1:18 shows that she was not living with St. Joseph, so she had to have been in Sts. Joachim & Anna's home (unless those two homes are the same):

Now the generation of Christ was in this wise. When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child, of the Holy Ghost.

(Although Cornelius à Lapide, S.J. and St. Jerome think this coming together doesn't simply mean cohabiting but also consummating the marriage, which they never did anyways; St. Thomas Aquinas seemed to have the opposite view.)
In Nazareth:
Lk. 1:26:

the angel Gabriel was sent from God into a city of Galilee, called Nazareth

